# regex have possibly one underscore and then at least one legal character

Tags: java, regex

I'm trying to define a pattern that allows possibly one underscore, and then it must have one or more legal characters from the set `"[\\w_]"` (i.e. either a word or an underscore). So `"_"` should return false, but `"__"` or `"a"` or `"\_a"` or `"a_"` should all return true.
I've  tried using the pattern

```
(_)?[\\w_]+
```

but it returns true on `_`. Do you know why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`\w` already contains the underscore character, all you have to do is to ensure that there is an other word character if the substring starts with an underscore:

```
_\\w+|[^\\W_]\\w*
```

or to not start the pattern with an alternation, you can do:

```
\\w(?:(?<=_)\\w+|(?<!_)\\w*)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a lookahead assertion in your regex as:

```
_(?=\w)
```

Note `\w` already includes an underscore as it includes following character sets `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`

Comment: i think this solution will fail with some inputs check this demo https://regex101.com/r/NjbpIj/2 and check my solution https://regex101.com/r/NjbpIj/1 or maybe my mistake i don't use it correctly?

Comment: Or, may be I didn't understand the problem correctly :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use this regex `[a-zA-Z]{1,}|[a-zA-Z_\/]{2,}` :

For inputs

```
   "_"      -> false
   "__"     -> true 
   "a"      -> true
   "_a"     -> true
   "a_"     -> true
```

## regex demon